# rewrite everything except files and directories

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to create a .htaccess rewriting rule for everything except existing files or folders, but cannot figure out what the problem seems to be.

My Code now is this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(-f|-d)$
RewriteRule .* index.html
```

i dont want to create a rule for everything except the allready existing files and folders in case i create aything else on the server.

the rewriting works properly but the exeptions do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the right code for this need is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #exeption for files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d #exeption for dirs
RewriteRule .* index.html
```